# Disable Result set cache for Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, powerbi, tableau-api, powerquery, looker

I am trying decide which tool works best for my organization. For that reason I am testing performance of powerbi, looker and tableau against bigQuery etc. Since this is a benchmarking exercise and I am planning to test it for multiple iterations, I want to disable the result set caching property of big Query. In the official documentation, they are letting us disable by passing query config `use_query_cache=False`

Since I am connecting from front end tools, I am not really sure how to pass this parameter. Can someone help in achieving this? or alternative options if available?

Comment: An alternative option would be to create a custom solution and disable cache on the API level. I wrote a starter project which uses this [option](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-bigquery/search?q=useQueryCache) and in fact has to disable the cache to let the test finish successfully. This is mentioned in README [here](https://github.com/winwiz1/crisp-bigquery#usage-limits)

Answer (score 0):

I've not tried this, but I'd think it could be passed like other options.

In this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/connect-data/desktop-connect-bigquery), they have code that looks like this:

```
Source = GoogleBigQuery.Database(
             [BillingProject="Include-Billing-Project-Id-Here", UseStorageApi=false])
```

I'd expect your parameter to look similar. I.e.

```
Source = GoogleBigQuery.Database(
             [BillingProject="Include-Billing-Project-Id-Here", UseQueryCache=false])
```

Comment: I just tried your suggestion in the query editor. It doesn't seem to be working. Here's what I have in Query editor ```let
    Source = GoogleBigQuery.Database([BillingProject="xyz-poc-eval",UseQueryCache=false]),
    #"vbi-ms-poc-eval" = Source{[Name="vbi-ms-poc-eval"]}[Data],
    TPCDS_DEV_Schema = #"vbi-ms-poc-eval"{[Name="TPCDS_DEV",Kind="Schema"]}[Data],
    DATE_DIM_Table = TPCDS_DEV_Schema{[Name="DATE_DIM",Kind="Table"]}[Data]
in
    DATE_DIM_Table ```

Comment: Not working as in throws an error or what?

Comment: Doesn't throw any error. When the same query is fired from powerbi, the subsequent queries use the result cache.